# applying a different theme for panels using extjs in dojo web application

Tags: css, extjs, dojo

I am trying to apply a different theme to panels I have displayed on different pages. I am not not that accustomed to working with css and javascript so some help would be appreciated.

```
      <div id="rules" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" 
           data-dojo-props="back:'DASHBOARD',moveTo:'general'" class="style1">
                         REALTIME-COUNTS
        </h1>
        <center>
           <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.RoundRect" style="width: 1200px; 
                      height: 400px;" shadow="true">
           <h4>TOTAL DAILY RESULTS</h4>
           <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:false">
           <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 70%; height:342px;"></div>  
           </div>
           </div>
       </center>
```

Now I have a theme.css file added into the project but not sure how to do this. I want to apply to the panel/view above named 'rules'. Is this possible or am I way off here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your theme.css file look like? If you're just trying to apply styles to the "rules" panel and not any other panel at all, then you can do something like this:

```
#rules {
  width: 100%;
}
```

but if you were trying to reuse this CSS elsewhere then just add a class to your div (with id rules) like this:

```
<div id="rules" class="mobileView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
```

and then add a css rule like this:

```
.mobileView {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I could probably help you a little better if you put something into JSFiddle.

Comment: thanks. Was fiddling around with it and figured it out but your response did confirm it.